# Issue in merge array and delete duplicate all array

Tags: php, arrays

I've merged two arrays. A duplicate entry is a deleted. Let me explain the as an example (I have compare array using `user_id`)

```
$array1 = Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 44
[user_id] => 2
[name] => jina_testl
[profilePhoto] =>
)
)

$array2 = Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 2
[user_id] => 3
[name] => demo_test1
[profilePhoto] =>
)
[1] => Array
(
[id] => 3
[user_id] => 2
[name] => abc
[profilePhoto] =>
)
[2] => Array
(
[id] => 4
[user_id] => 4
[name] => test
[profilePhoto] =>
)
)
```

I have merged array1 and array2 and duplicate array remove. I get the following output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 44
[user_id] => 2
[name] => jina_testl
[profilePhoto] =>
)
[1] => Array
(
[id] => 2
[user_id] => 3
[name] => demo_test1
[profilePhoto] =>
)
[3] => Array
(
[id] => 4
[user_id] => 4
[name] => abc
[profilePhoto] =>
))
```

But I want such an output like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[id] => 2
[user_id] => 3
[name] => demo_test1
[profilePhoto] =>
)
[1] => Array
(
[id] => 4
[user_id] => 4
[name] => abc
[profilePhoto] =>
))
```

Comment: So you want user_id 2 to be updatet with second array, that makes sense. But user_id 3 is also removed in your desired output, why's that?

Comment: It's not really clear why the array with id 44 and id 3 are excluded. Do you merge on user_id and if so why remove both of them and not keep one?

Comment: @GerarddeVisser  User_id 2 is in both arrays so I have to remove from both arrays.
But I can't do that

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following: first get all the user_ids that we do not want to be included, by taking the intersection of the two columns.
If we then merge the two separate arrays and exclude the ones that are present in the array of unwanted IDs we should get our final result.

```
$userId = 'user_id';

$userIdsArray1 = array_column($array1, $userId);
$userIdsArray2 = array_column($array2, $userId);

// If we then take the negation we should get something similar to an exclusive or.
// Thus those in one or the other but not in both arrays.
$unwantedUserIds = array_intersect($userIdsArray1, $userIdsArray2);

$result = [];

foreach (array_merge($array1, $array2) as $record) {
    if (!in_array($record[$userId], $unwantedUserIds)) {
        $result[] = $record;
    }
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($result, true), '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 3
            [name] => demo_test1
            [profilePhoto] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [user_id] => 4
            [name] => test
            [profilePhoto] => 
        )

)
```